# Street View Publish Navigation angle changed

Tags: google-streetview-publish

After Getting Panoid I went through the batchUpdate function  where i can establish link,
Link established correctly but the navigation arrow angle changed , how to do the proper navigation arrow in the street view publish.

I am updating latlng and connection.

Can anyone tell what is the reason why the angle is changed..

Can any one tell the arrow position is due to latlng or heading or anything else?

Comment: Could you provide your code snippet?

Comment: just can u explain how to set heading of two panos...

Comment: how latlng is related to pov

Answer (score 0):

According the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/streetview/publish/reference/rpc/google.streetview.publish.v1#google.streetview.publish.v1.Connection), you can not set the heading of a connection, you can only set the **photoId** of the **linked pano** : the arrows are then oriented in the direction of the linked pano lat/lng.

But you can set the heading of a photo, and that's a good practice to set all headings to the same direction if you have many panoramas, in order to help the user orient himself in your panoramas constellation.

Cheers.